# Manhwa/webtoon where the mc relives the last moments of different people

Tags: story-identification, manga

The mc commits suicide and as a punishment for suicide, he is sent to relive the last moments of people about to die. He experiences many lives as a schoolboy, streamer, gangster, businessman, model etc. He tries to change the fate everytime to extend his life.

Comment: Can you remember when you read this? What some of the things he did to change the fate? If you remember anything else and want to add it in you can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking *for I Will Die Soon*

The MC is being punished by Death itself because of his suicide. He will have to experience death 13 times by living throughout the experiences of different people.

The pictures below take place during his first meeting with Death while he is revived as the businessman you spoke of.

*Click to enlarge*
[image: Meeting with Death 1]
[image: Meeting with Death 2]
[image: Meeting with Death 3]